# R Copula package. Erros when defining a mvdc with a different copula families

Tags: r

I am using the `copula` package in R.

I have fitted several copulas to a bivariate dataset, and want to combine the best one - which turned out to be a Plackett copula, with the estimated marginal distributions (referred to as Marg1 and Marg2; they do not seem to be important here) in an `mvdc` object. However, I get an error message when I try to do this (in the example, I have replaced the `plackettCopula` object obtained from fitting the copula to data using `fitCopula` for simplicity. Obviously, I want to use the one I have fitted to data):

```
> mvdc(copula = plackettCopula(0.5), margins = c(Marg1$distname, Marg2$distname), paramMargins = list(as.list(Marg1$estimate), as.list(Marg2$estimate)), check = T)

    Multivariate Distribution Copula based ("mvdc")
     @ copula:
    Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

When I do the same with a Normal copula, I get no such error message:

```
> mvdc(copula = normalCopula(0.5), margins = c(Marg1$distname, Marg2$distname), paramMargins = list(as.list(Marg1$estimate), as.list(Marg2$estimate)), check = T)

    Multivariate Distribution Copula based ("mvdc")
     @ copula:
    Normal copula, dim. d = 2 
    Dimension:  2 
    Parameters:
      rho.1   = 0.5
     @ margins:
    [1] "gev"    "glogis"
       with 2 (not identical)  margins; with parameters (@ paramMargins) 
    List of 2
     $ :List of 3
      ..$ shape: num -0.2502235
      ..$ scale: num 0.1824798
      ..$ loc  : num 0.9315861
     $ :List of 3
      ..$ location: num 0.9918519
      ..$ scale   : num 0.05639447
      ..$ shape   : num 1.10499
```

Can anyone tell me what this error message means, and is there a way to fix it? It appears that I get the same error message for many other copulas, e.g. gumbel, clayton, frank, joe, amh, etc...

Also, the `mvdc` object seems to be OK even with this error message, and I seem to be able to simulate from the fitted `mvdc`-object and if I make three `mvdc`-objects based on the Plackett-copula with different parameters, I get very different results. Does this mean that the object is actually working well, in spite of the error message? I get the following plots based on this `mvdc`-object with different values of the plackett-copula parameter:

```
> mvdc1 = mvdc(copula = plackettCopula(1), margins = c(Marg1$distname, Marg2$distname), paramMargins = list(as.list(Marg1$estimate), as.list(Marg2$estimate)), check = T)
> mvdc2 = mvdc(copula = plackettCopula(10), margins = c(Marg1$distname, Marg2$distname), paramMargins = list(as.list(Marg1$estimate), as.list(Marg2$estimate)), check = T)
> mvdc3 = mvdc(copula = plackettCopula(60), margins = c(Marg1$distname, Marg2$distname), paramMargins = list(as.list(Marg1$estimate), as.list(Marg2$estimate)), check = T)
> par(mfrow=c(1,3))
> plot(rMvdc(1000, mvdc1))
> plot(rMvdc(1000, mvdc2))
> plot(rMvdc(1000, mvdc3))
```

[image]

Any help in how to get around or deal with this is much appreciated.